# redux persist in the next js project persist:root is not creating localstorage

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

using the nextjs framework the redux-persist is not creating the local storage values. After login the persist:root is not showing in the local

In the reactjs framework, I have tried the redux persist the persist:root created in the local storage but in the nextjs framework the same method I am following the errors not coming but the persist:root is not showing
in the local storage

//store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import nextConnectRedux from 'next-connect-redux';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session';

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage: storage,
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

const middleware = [thunk];

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?   
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    }) : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    );

const store = () => {
    return createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    {},
    enhancer
)};

const nextConnect = nextConnectRedux(store)

export default nextConnect;
```

// index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import nextConnect from '../store';
import Route from '../routes';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    const persistor = persistStore(nextConnect);
    return (
        <Provider store={nextConnect}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <BrowserRouter>
           <Route/>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want the persist:root in the local storage to be showed

Answer (score 0):

if you are rendering React on the server, you cant use redux-persist with default configs
When you are using redux-persist with the default configuration, means you are storing your data on browser storage and you don’t have a browser on the server
The following implementation shows you how to integrate Redux Persist into Next.js

*rootReducer.js*

[image: *rootReducer.js*]

*store.js*

[image: *store.js*]

*_app.js*

[image: *_app.js*]
That's it

> resource
>   [Redux Persist with Next.js](https://www.robinwieruch.de/redux-persist-next-js)